# vcpkg install package Error, Run vcvarsall.bat to get Visual Studio env failed with exit code 1

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vcpkg

when I install any package,vcpkg throw these error said can not get visual studio env . I am sure I had install visual studio 2017,but may it not work

[the error image like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY8ee.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem when I deleted:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

(`CURRENT USER`, NOT `LOCAL_MACHINE`)

I refer to this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/13890